# Read And Write XML file content to another XML file below a certain tag

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

Guys i just wanna know how i can copy a content from one xml file and write it to another xml file below after certain tag ends in JAVA Language.

Here's my xmlfile1:

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.eventlistener</groupId>
      <artifactId>Pel</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

xmlfile2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>autointelli</groupId>
  <artifactId>proj_autointelli_internal_gopalakrishnan_execute_a_given_command_and_send_output_in_email</artifactId>
  <version>19.0</version>
  <name>proj_autointelli_internal_gopalakrishnan_execute_a_given_command_and_send_output_in_email</name>
  <description>new project</description>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>guvnor-m2-repo</id>
      <name>Guvnor M2 Repo</name>
      <url>/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</project>
```

need to paste the content of xmlfile1 to xmlfile2 just below after the description tag ends without overwriting the content already present.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing is easiest with XSLT. Assuming XSLT 3.0 (available in the Saxon library), transform xmlfile2 with

```
<transform version="3.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
<template match="description">
  <copy-of select="., doc('xmlfile1.xml')"/>
</template>
</transform>
```